# How can I add multiple TextViews inside a Button

Tags: android, button, textview

I'm developing a calendar in which I need to show a big text inside of many cells
The button has a text that represents the number of the day how can I attach another textView inside of it?

Comment: `How can I add multiple TextViews inside a Button` You can't. Button is not a container. Consider using a GridView, instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can surround the button with a FrameLayout and then add a textview within the FrameLayout. If the text doesn't show try using bringToFront()

layout:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_frame"
            >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/get_more"
            android:id="@+id/get_more"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"

        />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/linearTimer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="123"
             >
    </FrameLayout>
```

Activity:

```
 countDownView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.linearTimer);

 countDownView.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add TextViews in a Button. What you can do is use a layout (Relative/Linear/Frame/etc) to encapsulate your Textviews. Then you will set an onClickListener to the layout!

You XML will look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Obviously, you need to add attributes to it. And also set an onClickListener to the RelativeLayout (or whatever layout you wanna use)!

Comment: Thanks for your response! :) but i Need the text inside of the button :( but as I mention the button already has a text (the number of the day)